# Fluent Linq to Entities - No edmx files

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-entities

Is there a "Fluent Linq To Entites" that I can use to Setup my dataContext without having to map anything through diagram files?

All I need is to map my db tables to certain domain classes without any need for Lazy-Loading.
I tried using LinqToSql but it was a No-Go since my domain classes all inherit from base classes.

**Note:** We can only use .NET 3.5

Answer (score 2):

If you can get away from using Entity Framework, you could use Fluent NHibernate + AutoMapping. http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping

Or you could use Linq 2 SQL by decorating your entity with attributes.

Like:

```
[Table(Name="Product")]
public class Product
{
  [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert]
  internal int Id {get;set;}

  [Column]
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then access it using the dbcontext like:

```
ctx.GetTable<Product>().SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id == 1);
```

Along those lines, wrote that off top of my head but you get the gist.

I would go Fluent+AutoMapping.

Answer (score 1):

There has recently been a [CTP release of Entity Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4e094902-aeff-4ee2-a12d-5881d4b0dd3e&displaylang=en) that provides support for a "Code First" or "Code Only" style of development.  I believe those libraries will allow you to setup your context without a map.  However, I don't think that there is anything currently released for Entity Framework which will do what you're looking for.

Comment: Correct, but note that it requires .NET 4.